# Invariants of the group $SO(2)$

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, lie-algebras, invariant-theory, classical-invariant-theory

Let $V_d$ be the complex vector space of binary forms of degree $d$ endowed with the natural
action of the special orthogonal  group $SO(2).$ Consider the corresponding action of the
group $SO(2)$ on the coordinate ring $\mathbb{C}[V_d]$ and let $\mathbb{C}[V_d]^{SO(2)}$ the algebra of $SO(2)$-invariant polynomial functions.

What we know about the algebra $\mathbb{C}[V_d]^{SO(2)}$: minimal generating set, Poincare series, ... ?

In the case of the  group $SL_2$ the situation is classical and algebra of invariants of binary form is well-studied but what about binary form invariants of the group $SO(2)?$

I hope the problem was already solved in 19th century. Can anyone tell me a good reference?

Comment: $SO(2)$ is Abelian so all its irreducible representations are abelian.   You now need to be more specific about how you define $V_d$: are they polynomial maps $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{C}$ or are they polynomial maps $\mathbb{C}^2\to\mathbb{C}$? In the first case the only invariants are functions of $r^2=x^2+y^2$. In the second case  there are no invariant polynomials  in the complex variables $z_1,z_2$.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu, all its irreducible representations are Abelian = all its irreducible representations are 1-dimensional, of course.

Comment: @LSpice Yes of course.  But the  span of the monomial $z_1^mz_2^n$ is an irreducible representation with  weight $m+n$. On the other hand, if we allow  complex conjugate variable  then the  span of $x=z^m\;\bar{z}^n$  has weight $m-n$  so  we get invariant monomials when $m=n$.  Thus the need to precisely define $V_d$.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu, right; I was just commenting on an obvious typo (for the poster's benefit), not arguing about mathematics.

Comment: @Liviu Nicolaescu. I am talking about polynomial function  invariant, so any such invariant is a polynomial of coefficients of the binary form. So $x^2+y^2$ is not invariant  but the  discriminant $b^2-ac$ of the  binary form $ax^2+2bxy+cy^2$ is a sample  of such invariants